# Has this approximation $0.41468250985111166$ a name?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

William Hughes calculated on WolframAlpha the expression
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{\operatorname{prime}(n)}}
$$
and got the approximate value $0.41468250985111166$. If one enters this value simply in WolramAlpha a symbol $P$ is shown in a font I don't know.

So I suppose the symbol has already a name.

If I look via search engines for the number a Brasilian Eric Campos Bastos Gueodes seems to have written in his book about this value in Brasilian language.

Comment: What does prime$(n)$ mean?

Comment: The $n$th prime

Comment: As a general rule in life, whenever faced with **integer sequences** or **decimal expansions**, use [*OEIS*](http://oeis.org/A051006) and [*ISC*](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced).

Comment: In OEIS is also an entry for $2*\mathcal{P}$ but I cant understand the explanations and hints given there. Its simply taken $2^{\phi(\operatorname{prime}(n))}$ in the sum with the Euler $\phi$-function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called the [prime constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_constant).

When you enter that number into WolframAlpha and you see the $\mathcal{P} = 0.41468250985111166$, notice that in the bottom right-hand corner of that cell it says "*$\mathcal{P}$ is the prime constant*", which links to the [Wolfram Mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeConstant.html) explaining what it is.